# Android unit test: mock BluetoothDevice and write to parcel

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking, android-bluetooth

I would like to ask about unit testing a class that has `BluetoothDevice` variable.

My object is a simple object that contains some primitive variable and a BluetoothDevice variable. My object is also parcelable.

Eventually my code works totally fine on the mobile device but I have strange error when I run my unit tests.

I mocked the BluetoothDevice in the test class as shown below:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest=Config.NONE)
public class BluetoothDeviceTest {

    @Mock
    BluetoothDevice device1;

    @Before
    public void initMocks(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        when(device1.getAddress()).thenReturn("01:02:03:04:05:06");
        when(device1.getName()).thenReturn("device767b1");
        when(device1.getBondState()).thenReturn(BOND_NONE);
    }
}
```

In my object among other primitives I use:

- I use `out.writeParcelable(mBluetoothDevice,0);` inside `@Override public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)` method.
- I use `mBluetoothDevice = in.readParcelable(BluetoothDevice.class.getClassLoader());` inside `protected MyObject(Parcel in)` constructor.

The unit test that tests parcelling of my object instance fails with an exception
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Once again please note that when my code runs totally fine and parcelling works good in the mobile app I work on. Only unit test is acting strange.

I suspect this is because my mocked `BluetoothDevice` variable is shorter in the parcel than a normal real instance and the order of the data fields in the parcel gets messed up.

Has anybody unit tested with a mocked `BluetoothDevice` and can give me some hint ? Thank you

Comment: To avoid using Robolectric (i.e. you want JUnit only), you have to mock the Parcel properly, no faking will work. I do have a simple implementation of how that might work, but it's limited to the Parcelable problem only (nothing to do with Bluetooth). Here it is: https://gist.github.com/milosmns/7f6448a3602595948449d3bfaff9b005

Answer (score 5):

Late answer... but if anybody need that.
Robolectric has now a class **ShadowBluetoothDevice**

Usable this way : `ShadowBluetoothDevice.newInstance("00:11:22:33:AA:BB")`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Since ShadowBluetoothDevice.newInstance() is deprecated, it is also possible to create a mock instance via bluetooth adapter:

```
val bluetoothManager = context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as? BluetoothManager
        val bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager?.adapter
val mockedBluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter?.getRemoteDevice("00:11:22:33:FF:EE")
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to connect to a BLE device, an app needs to obtain a BluetoothDevice object. This can be done using one of
three methods:

- By scanning: a BluetoothDevice object is returned for each scanned advertising packet in a callback
  parameter ScanResult.
- By obtaining a list of bonded devices using BluetoothAdapter#getBondedDevices().
- By creating a device object using BluetoothAdapter#getRemoteDevice(String address).

When a BluetoothDevice object is obtained using the last method (or by creating a new object with new
BluetoothDevice(address)), a connection attempt to it will work only if:

- The device has a PUBLIC address or is bonded, or
- The device has been scanned at least once before connection attempt
  since Bluetooth adapter have been started

Source: https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/blogs/1046/what-to-keep-in-mind-when-developing-your-ble-andr/